# Fix gradient colors on TeeChart for a javascript

Tags: javascript, gradient, teechart

Hi guys we need to fix gradient colors. We are trying to change min and max with setMinMax on right axis.

Before the changing it was like that: 
[image]
After changing the result is:
[image]

The gradient does not look so good any ideas why these changes affect the gradient.

Thanks

Comment: What exact versions are you comparing? Could you please post a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Yeray I am not comparing between versions this occurs when executing SetMinMax and re-drawing the chart again.

Comment: If it's an Area series, have you tried to change the `origin` property in the series? An example we can run as-is would help here

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the an example page:

http://en.1009.binarate.com/prosite/teechart .

The problem occurs after changing min and max on the right axis and scrolling the gradient changes its original proportions. Here is the function which handles the y zoom of the chart.

```
 function yz() {
            var l = sd[sd.length - 1][1],
             h = 0;
            for (var i = sd.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var dc = sd[i],
                    dcox =Chart1.axes.bottom.calc(dc[0])
                if (dcox > 0 && dc[1] > h) {
                    h = dc[1];
                }
                if (dcox > 0 && dc[1] < l) {
                    l = dc[1];
                }
                if (dcox < 0)
                    break;

            }
            Chart1.axes.right.setMinMax(l * 0.99990, h * 1.00010),
            Chart1.axes.right.increment = (Chart1.axes.right.maximum - Chart1.axes.right.minimum) / 10;
            Chart1.getSeries(0).origin = l * 0.99990;
        }
```

The main changes are in the above function.

Comment: This looks as a modification of the question more than an answer. You may prefer to edit the question adding this to it.

Comment: Anyway, the link you posted gives a black page to me. I can see no charts on it